# Initialize Nissan with Rogue and call the method drive() to it make sure it prints out

Tags: objective-c

I am completely new to Objective c. How do I initialize Nissan with Rogue and call the method drive() to it make sure it prints out?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
#import "Car.h"  

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{ 
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        Car *drive = [[Car alloc] init];         
        Car *Nissan =[[Car alloc] init];         

       [Nissan drive];                  
       Nissan.model=@"Rogue";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Are you getting any error? Or aren't you getting console logs?

Answer (score 0):

For the basic implementation, you can follow this structure.

> Car.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *model;
- (void)drive;
@end
```

> Car.m

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car
- (void)drive {
    NSLog(@"Car model is: %@", self.model);
}
@end
```

> main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Car *nissan = [[Car alloc]init];
        nissan.model = @"Rogue";
        [nissan drive];
    }
    return 0;
}
```